# How do I download a package from apt-get without installing it?

Tags: debian, apt-get

I have a computer without a [NIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller), and I want to install some programs in it via USB memory, but how can I download a program from [apt-get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool) without installing it?

Comment: This can be moved to SuperUser, right?

Comment: Or to [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com), where it has since been [asked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47865/how-do-i-use-apt-get-to-only-download-packages) and [answered](http://askubuntu.com/a/47877/20358).

Comment: For Debian start https://packages.debian.org/stable/  Drill down.  Very near (way down) the page for the package is a list of architectures you can download.  Click to download.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

There are a least these `apt-get` extension packages that can help:

```
apt-offline - offline apt package manager
apt-zip - Update a non-networked computer using apt and removable media
```

This is specifically for the case of wanting to *download* where you have network access but to *install* on another machine where you do not.

Otherwise, the  `--download-only` option to `apt-get` is your friend:

```
 -d, --download-only
     Download only; package files are only retrieved, not unpacked or installed.
     Configuration Item: APT::Get::Download-Only.
```

Comment: OK, believe I read that in the man but I write:sudo apt-get install -d <package>

Comment: apt-get -d doesn't download things if it is already installed

Comment: This will download package to current working directory: `aptitude download <package_name>`. It avoids problems faced by `apt-get` when the package is already installed

Comment: @biocyberman: Could you please post that as a separate answer?  It's simpler than any of the other suggested answers, but it's easy to miss since it's just a comment.

Comment: If you're into wrappers, look into `wajig` which I have been using for years. It has a download command too (and wraps `aptitude`).

Comment: @BrooksMoses: I can't do that anymore, the question is closed.

Comment: This works for me on Linux Mint 17: apt-get download <package>

Comment: More recent distros can also do `apt download <package_name>` (similar to biocyberman's answer but I think `apt` is now more common than `aptitude`).

Comment: Suggestions: Perhaps add `apt download <package_name>` to the answer and add the information that it's downloaded to `/var/cache/apt/archives/`

Comment: @DarkTrick. Sure. But my _ten year old_ answer already started by saying that there is more than one way to skin this cat...

Answer (score 134):

Try

```
apt-get -d install <packages>
```

It is documented in `man apt-get`.

Just for clarification; the downloaded packages are located in the apt package
cache at

```
/var/cache/apt/archives
```

Comment: Does this work if the package is already up-to-date on the system which `apt-get -d`  is executed on?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, nope it does not. But in this case you could use dpkg-repack (apt-get install dpkg-repack + man should be easy enough) - although this is quite far-fetched in relation to the original question. Alternatively there is always http://packages.debian.org/

Answer (score 52):

Don't forget the option "-o", which lets you download anywhere you want, although you have to create "archives", "lock" and "partial" first (the command prints what's needed).

```
apt-get install -d -o=dir::cache=/tmp whateveryouwant
```

Comment: If you're running as a non-root user you can do something like: mkdir -p /tmp/archives/partial && apt-get -d -o dir::cache=/tmp -o Debug::NoLocking=1 install package

Comment: +1 for mentioning -o option. Was searching for this information for almost an hour now.

Comment: On 12.04, when I ran:
``apt-get -d -o=dir::cache=/tmp/pkg rabbitmq-server
E: Invalid operation rabbitmq-server``
It should be :
``$ apt-get download -o=dir::cache=/tmp/pkg rabbitmq-server                                                                      
Get:1 Downloading rabbitmq-server 2.7.1-0ubuntu4 [2,745 kB]
13% [1 rabbitmq-server 361 kB/2,745 kB 13%]``

Comment: This doesn't appear to download anything if the package is already up-to-date on the system.

Comment: you need to include the "install" command in the request. Thus "apt-get install -d -o=dir::cache=/tmp packagename"

Comment: I need the -o option, without the system does not download the packages.