# What is the Debian equivalent of "requirements.txt" in Python for managing packages?

Tags: python, linux, debian, pip, dpkg

I'm shipping a Python app for deployment on Debian servers. Providing a `requirements.txt` file with a list of all needed Python packages is very convenient when installing the app, especially when accompanied with a `Makefile` to automatically install from it using `pip`.

But as you know some Python packages depend on Linux system packages (Debian in this case), and it would be great if I could provide a similar file with my project to install them all in one step, and define the `Makefile` rule to automate it.

Do `dpkg` or `apt` provide such functionality?

Comment: Yes... dpkg provides a functionality which you can use to achieve similar effect. But people use tools like Puppet, which are more suited for such purposes.

Comment: The installation hurdle and learning curve of configuration management systems is not worth it for simple apps like mine.

Comment: In that case you can use dpkg itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just listing the required packages as arguments to `apt install` command, since there were not many of them.
I put the command is a `Dockerfile` and creating a Docker image is now my preferred way to automate how an app gets created and deployed.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly dump all the packages installed by `dpkg`, but that's probably not what you want to do - you'll end up getting thounsands of packages unrelated to your software, and possibly breaking the system, if it's a different debian version.

My advice is getting your software to a fresh debian machine and try to `pip install` everything from your `requirements.txt`. As python package installation fails (because of missing debian packages), make a text file with a newline separated list of the needed debian packages.

Then, just `cat my-deb-dependencies | xargs apt-get install` on every new system.

This takes some manual work - I don't think there's a *reliable* way of automating it.

Comment: Yes, that works. But I wish cool features of `requirements.txt` files like requiring particular version numbers, pre-downloading packages or comments were officially supported by `apt`.

Comment: @aalizadeh you can certainly [pre-download packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419268/how-do-i-download-a-package-from-apt-get-without-installing-it) and [install specific versions of packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20839603/using-apt-get-to-get-specific-version-of-eclipse) (remember, though, that they may no longer be available).

Comment: @aalizadeh although you can't (easily) do it from a single package list file, if that's what you meant. But it's easy enough to script around.

Answer (score 1):

It is confusing to mix distribution packing (`apt`) with python's packaging(`pip`); if possible fulfill your dependencies through distribution provided packages. Then package using Debian's packaging method declaring the dependencies in the Depends: section of the `debian/control` file.

There is heaps of information available on the [Debian Python Guide](https://wiki.debian.org/Python/LibraryStyleGuide).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your dependencies. If you have in `requirements.txt` dependencies like `pycurl`, then there's already a Debian package called `python3-pycurl`.
Then simply add to your `debian/control`:

```
Package: mypackage
Architecture: all
Depends: ${misc:Depends}, ${python3:Depends}, python3-pycurl
```

There are [many Python packages](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/python/) already ported to Debian packages.

However in some cases the Debian package might include only outdated version or there's some Pypi package that hasn't been ported to Debian yet. Since Debian 12, there's been changes to the recommended way of installing Python packages. On Python side there are certain recommendation for [externally managed environments](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/externally-managed-environments/#externally-managed-environments). Basically distributions should create

- `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` system package managed by distribution
- `/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages` packages installed by local administrator

Anyway you can still use dedicated `venv` for each project. This way possible conflicting dependencies between project won't collide.

```
python3 -m venv /usr/share/python3-myenv
source /usr/share/python3-myenv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

However in order to properly package the virtualenv approach you could use [dh-virtualenv](https://github.com/spotify/dh-virtualenv):

```
apt install dh-virtualenv
```

`debian/control` should include:

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), python, dh-virtualenv (>= 0.8)
```

and in `debian/rules` use:

```
%:
      dh $@ --with python-virtualenv
```

this will ensure that dependencies in `requirements.txt` will be installed. Note, your project must include `setup.py` file. [See documentation](https://dh-virtualenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#simple-usecase) for more information.